# CSS limit to number of lines

Tags: css

Is there a limit in number of lines you can input per css file?

I've got around 2800 lines and I cannot seem to target my html elements. I was able to do that before.

Comment: it is a sign for bad design. and thers no limit for css file size / lines

Comment: 2800 lines?? How is that possible?

Comment: Is your CSS valid? Perhaps you have a breaking character somewhere that is nullifing any of your markup thereafter. Try this http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many lines do you have of javascript and html in the same file?

Comment: What do you mean bad design? Why can I not target any html elements in a page using Google inspector?

Comment: "2800 lines?? How is that possible?" = hire Wipro to do your markup.

Comment: @hybmg58 it's bad design in that it sounds like a very bloated CSS file. I can't imagine having to maintain a 2800 line css file.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no limit, beyond memory/disk space. If you can't target elements, you've probably got a syntax error in the file somewhere killing the later rules. If you're on Firefox/Chrome, pop up the error console (shift-ctrl-J) and it'll tell of you any parse errors its encountered.

Comment: Yes there is. Mind posting your CSS?

Comment: Then start chopping down the file into pieces until things start working again. Whatever's causing the problem will probably be in the last chunk cut.

Comment: @hybmg58 - have you validated it against the css validator?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no limitations on CSS such as file size and number of lines.  Have you tried other browsers?  Different browsers **might** have limitations on css files.

Worst case scenario, you can use multiple css files.